# autofill directories at several levels

Tags: python, python-3.x

Developing the topic:

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432965/Автозаполнение-директорий/1432977#1432977](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432965/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9/1432977#1432977) .

There is a directory 2022:
it contains folders

- 1 quarter
- January
- February
- March
- 2nd quarter
  .
  .
  .

```
import os

path_1= r'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog3\2022'

for i in os.listdir(path_1):
    path_2 = os.path.join(path_1,i)
    for j in os.listdir(path_2):
        file_name = '{}.docx'.format(j)
        path_3 = os.path.join(path_2,j,j+'.docx')
        print(path_3)
        with open(path_3,'w') as g:
            g.write('hello')

for i in os.listdir(path_1):
    file_name = '{}.docx'.format(i)
    path_2 = os.path.join(path_1,i,i+'.docx')
    with open(path_2,'w') as f:
        f.write('hello')
```

The task is to have in each folder: both the quarter and the month need to be created .doc with the folder name.
Like this

- 1 quarter

(1 квартал.docx )

- January

(January.docx)
.
.
.

The code I presented does this, but it only works 1 time. And if you swap the cycles, it will also give an error.
When restarting, it gives an error :

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog3\2022\I quarter\I quarter.docx\I квартал.docx.docx '
File "C:\Users\МВИДЕО\ргодѕ\ргод2\сһ_2.ру ", line 104, in 
with open(path_3,'w') as g:

I understand that when switching from one directory to another names .docx are appended even to an already existing one at the previous level .docx (a real word document), but since it is not a directory
an error comes out.

I assumed that I would delete all such docx.docx and it will work. But from everything I read, nothing helped

From what I read on this topic: via `isdir`,`isfile` - at startup, just sends everything to Fals

through `endwith' - also does not find a single file.

What do I need to fix? Well, in general, maybe there is a technique for quickly forming folders. For example, then I will need to add folders with weeks inside each month. and each also has its own documents, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try using pathlib module

Answer (score 0):

I made it!

```
path_1= r'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog3\2022'

dirs = list(os.walk(path_1))
second_level = dirs[0][1]
#takes catalogs


for i in second_level:
    file_name = '{}.docx'.format(i)
    path_2 = os.path.join(path_1,i,i+'.docx')
    with open(path_2,'w') as f:
        f.write('hello')
# make doc for each quarter

a=[]
for path,subdir,files in os.walk(path_1):
    for name in subdir:
        a.append((os.path.join(path,name).split(",")))
a=a[4:]
a_1 =sum(a,[])
# take month (final directory for each month)


for i in range(len(a_1)):
    os.chdir(a_1[i])
    aa = a_1[i]
    ab =aa.split('\\')[-1]
    file_name = '{}.docx'.format(ab)
    p = os.path.join(a_1[i],ab+'.docx')
    with open(p,'w') as f:
        f.write('')
# makes doc for each month
```